# Swagger Annotation - not to include parameter when there is no parameter?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-editor

I have swagger-jersey2-jaxrs 1.5.1-M2 integrated with Drop-wizard. I have generated the following yaml with the swagger annotations I have included on my resource and models:

```
    ---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "test Application"
tags:
- name: "test"
paths:
  /v1/test/version:
    get:
      tags:
      - "v1test"
      summary: "version number of test"
      description: "Returns version number of test"
      operationId: "getVersionAndBuildInfo"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters: 
      responses:
        404:
          description: "build number not found."
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            type: "array"
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/testInformation"
definitions:
  testInformation:
    properties:
      build:
        type: "string"
        description: "test build number"
      version:
        type: "string"
        description: "test version number"
      buildTimestamp:
        type: "string"
        description: "test build timestamp"
    description: "model for test version information"
```

notice that **parameters:** is include in the generated yaml from swagger. when I paste this in the swagger editor 2.0 it is throwing an error saying "Array is too short (0), minimum 1".

Is there a way not to generate the **parameters:** in yaml when the URL does not require any parameters? I didn't include any parameter annotation and it still shows up on the generated yaml.

Answer (score 0):

We had a bug in the JSON Schema for Swagger definitions that didn't allow for an empty parameters. This was fixed, and is going to be available in swagger-editor as well soon.

Please follow https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/395 to see when it is updated.

There's no point trying to 'solve' this issue in the generation process because the output is not wrong.